# How to get a specific part of a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string:

```
string = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXtext:hello,XXXXXXX'
```

I want to retrieve `hello`. `XXXXXXXX` is some random text. The only thing I know is that `hello` is between `text:` and `,`.

Comment: find index of both the text and then use substring function

Comment: Why there is  a colon `:` between text & hello ? Is `XXXXXXXXXXXXtext` is a key to an object?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to retrieve the text you need. Try this:

```js
var str = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXtext:hello,XXXXXXX';
var matches = /text\:(.+),/gi.exec(str);

console.log(matches[1]);
```

If there are multiple instances of `text:` within your string then you can use a loop to iterate through the result of `exec()` and retrieve them all.